# How can I speed up PouchDB?

Tags: performance, ionic-framework, pouchdb

Since replacing Mongodb with Pouchdb in my ionic app, the app feels a little sluggish, and I would like to know if there is a way to speed it up. The database we are talking about currently contains less than a 100 documents and is slow even when the usage is purely local. We are using secondary indexes. Is this the cause of this performance drop? Would we be better off using `allDocs()` and then searching manually trough the database? I read it would be faster, but the posts were over a year old and things may have changed since then. I also tried using the websql adapter, but it didn't really affect the speed. Are they other adapters or things I could try?

Comment: Your secondary indexes are functions or design documents?

Answer (score 1):

On such a small database, a secondary index would not be faster than allDocs in my experience. But I would not think the performance difference would be noticeable (I have used both on a small local database). You might try "compacting" the databases regularly if you have not already as this can make the database size smaller and more efficient. Like you, I have tried different adapters (IndexDb and websql) but could not see much difference in speed.